# Python threading.Lock not working as a mutex

Tags: python, multithreading

I'd always assumed a threading.Lock object would act as a mutex to prevent race conditions from occuring in a multithreading Python script, but I'm finding that either

1. my assumption is false (contradicting years of experience), or
2. Python itself has a bug (in, at the very least, versions 2.7-3.9) regarding this.

Theoretically, incrementing a value shared between two threads should be fine as long as you protect the critical section (ie the code incrementing that value) with a Lock, ie. mutex.

Running this code, I find mutexes in Python not to work as expected. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import threading
import time

Stop = False

class T(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self,list_with_int):
    self.mycount = 0
    self.to_increment = list_with_int
    super(T,self).__init__()

  def run(self,):
    while not Stop:
      with threading.Lock():
        self.to_increment[0] += 1
      self.mycount += 1

intList = [0]
t1 = T(intList)
t2 = T(intList)
t1.start()
t2.start()

Delay = float(sys.argv[1]) if sys.argv[1:] else 3.0

time.sleep(Delay)

Stop = True
t1.join()
t2.join()
total_internal_counts = t1.mycount + t2.mycount

print("Compare:\n\t{total_internal_counts}\n\t{intList[0]}\n".format(**locals()))

assert total_internal_counts == intList[0]
```

Comment: What is the expected and current output and how are they different?

Comment: Just now tried with Python 3.10, and things seem to be much better -- not a failure yet.  So Python 3.10 may have addressed a problem in mutual exclusion behavior, but could this really have escaped users' and developers' notice for so long? (Through one major and numerous minor releases?)

Comment: @Ahmed AEK This would be a "correct" / "expected" run:$ docker run --rm -it -v `pwd`/demo.py:/thrtest.py:ro python:3.10 bash
root@3df5c839851d:/# python thrtest.py
Compare:
 7556236
 7556236``` Whereas a bad run prints different integers and throws an AssertionError.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this is the answer, the lock object must be persistent and shared amongst the threads.

This works :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import threading
import time

Stop = False


class T(threading.Thread):

  lock = threading.Lock()
  def __init__(self,list_with_int):
    self.mycount = 0
    self.to_increment = list_with_int
    super(T,self).__init__()

  def run(self,):
    while not Stop:
      with self.lock:
        self.to_increment[0] += 1
      self.mycount += 1

intList = [0]
t1 = T(intList)
t2 = T(intList)
t1.start()
t2.start()

Delay = float(sys.argv[1]) if sys.argv[1:] else 3.0

time.sleep(Delay)

Stop = True
t1.join()
t2.join()
total_internal_counts = t1.mycount + t2.mycount

print("Compare:\n\t{total_internal_counts}\n\t{intList[0]}\n".format(**locals()))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> It's possible that...the lock object must be persistent and shared amongst the threads

That's exactly right. `threading.Lock()` is a *constructor* call. The `run` loop in your original example created a new `Lock` object for each iteration:

```py
while not Stop:
    with threading.Lock():         //creates a new Lock object each time 'round
        self.to_increment[0] += 1
```

You fixed it by creating a *single* `Lock` object that is used by all the threads and, by every iteration of the loop in each thread.

```py
class T(threading.Thread):

    // create one Lock object that will be shared by all instances of
    // class T
    //
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self,):    
        while not Stop:
            with self.lock:    // lock and release the one Lock object.
                self.to_increment[0] += 1
```

When you lock a `Lock` object, the only thing that it prevents is, it prevents other threads from locking the *same* `Lock` at the same time.